# Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

I am trying to compile code using gcc and run the executable, but it is throwing error:

```
gcc somefile.c -o somefile
```

compilation goes through successfully. But, when I try to execute it:

```
$sh somefile
```

It results in: **Syntax error: "(" unexpected**. Among the output files, I dont see somefile.o, but instead, I see somefile.c~

The contents of the file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("hi");
}
```

Context: I am new to programming in linux, and wanted to start out with simple programs. I am running ubuntu 64 bit on a virtual machine, with gcc, g++, etc installed. After that I created a sample file as mentioned above ("somefile.c"), and tried the steps mentioned above, but could not execute. My goal is to compile and execute a sample C or Cpp code on ubuntu using gcc or g++. Please help.

Comment: The `somefile.c~` is probably a copy of your `somefile.c` made by your text editor to maintain your file "up to date" if you forget to save it. I remember that `gedit` does that.

Comment: "sh somefile" -- That's not how you execute C programs.

Comment: @JimBalter: arguably, there is no such thing as a "C program". It's an *executable*, as opposed to a "shell script".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your `somefile` is executable binary, **it's not shell script**. you should execute it by:

```
$./somefile
```

Comment: Please refrain from telling U**x 'programmers' that there is anything else other than shell scripts - either they won't believe you, or their head will explode :)

Answer (score 3):

To execute file you just have to do

`$./somefile`

`sh` is used when you've to execute a shell script