# C binary : syntax error: `(' unexpected

Tags: c, makefile, cross-platform, exe

I am having a weird error. Before I begin, my question is not a copy of [Syntax error unexpected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464767/syntax-error-unexpected).

I have a C file. If I do `gcc code.c -Wall`. It creates `a.out`. And I am able to run `./a.out`. No errors and no warnings.

In my case I have to compile this code for another compiler (to run on another architecture [powerpc-8540-netbsd-gcc]). In that makefile also I get no error during compilation and linking. But when I run it, I get :

```
./name_of_exe[1]: syntax error: `(' unexpected
```

`name_of_exe` is my executable.

What could be causing this error?

Comment: What is the *another compiler*? What is the exact command issued by `make` to compile it? What is the code?

Comment: try `gcc code.c -Wall`. Enable all warnings

Comment: Isn't like `syntax error` is produced by the compiler and you're saying at runtime? I'm confused.

Comment: @SouravGhosh same feeling here

Comment: and what is that `[1]` thing?

Comment: could you check the result of `head ./name_of_exe`?

Comment: This is turning into a game of 20 questions. Voting to close.

Comment: How could we guess what the error cause is if we don't know what and how your program does? ...Possibly your program analyzes some envronment data, and some string does not contain what the program expects? ...Or may be it reads some file?

Comment: This  error is because of your cross compilation is improper. Your device architecture not able to run the binary format you have. Check your cross compilation again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused due to error in linking a dynamic library, specifically "libc". The version I was using was the reason behind the error.

Linking to a newer version solved this bizarre error.